npm build for github pages links requests to base url instead of sub url
Running npm build using github actions and then deploying to github pages using my gh-pages branch. The index.html file loads fine from  https://user.github.io/, but all other http requests go to that url instead of where the resource is, https://user.github.io/Project/
Here is one of the requests:
GET /static/css/main.15693543.css HTTP/2
Host: user.github.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0
Accept: text/css,/;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https:/user.github.io/Project/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: style
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Priority: u=2
TE: trailers
*Note I replaced urls with user and Project
The file is there when I go to https://user.github.io/static/css/main.15693543.css. Just need to build where all file locations point to Project/static/~ and not /static/~
Here is the root html straight from the build:
Tried:

adding npm run build --public-path=/Project/
adding npm run build --base-url=/Project/
enabling and disabling jekyll
adding  to header in html
manually changing paths in each file of the branch which works, but thats not efficient

My temporary solution is a simple find and replace

name: Find and Replace
uses: jacobtomlinson/gha-find-replace@v3
with:
find: "/static/"
replace: "/Project/static/"
regex: false

Edit: The issue may be that going to https://user.github.io/ gives github 404, going to https://user.github.io/Project gives the index.html file. Requests for resources go to https://user.github.io/, which is 404
